# How select nodes combining preceding-sibling and following sibling?

Tags: xpath, xslt

I want to select all nodes preceding-sibling `A` and following-sibling `A`, excluding following-sibling `C` and `D`

XML :

```
<XMLCODE>
    <ex>
        <z>bla</z>
        <z>bla</z>
        <A/>
        <k>want</k>
        <b>want</b>
        <A/>
        <b>bla</b>
        <h>bla</h>
        <C/>
        <z>bla</z>
        <D/>
        <e>bla</e>
        <A/>
        <j>want</j>
        <A/>
        <i>bla</i>
        <C/>
        <y>bla</y>
        <C/>
        <y>bla</y>
        
    </ex>
</XMLCODE>
```

output:

```
<k>want</k>
<b>want</b>
<j>want</j>
```

I tried

```
//*[
    preceding-sibling::*[self::A ]
     and 
    following-sibling::*[self::A ]
    ]
    [not(self::A)]
```

Thanks

Comment: The logic you state is not very clear. Looking at the expected result, it seems that the `A` elements come in pairs, and you want the nodes that are inside each pair. Would this be a correct formulation of the rule?

Comment: P.S. Please state which version of XSLT your processor supports (and do this In all your questions regarding XSLT).

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by your requirements? You say you want `<b>want</b>` but it does have both following-siblings `<C/>` and `<D/>`; it seems to me this contradicts your requirement "excluding following-sibling C and D"

Comment: I use Saxon-PE 9.9.1.7.   Yes you formulated the rule better than I did. I need to select the nodes between each pair of A

Comment: Good question, Jessika!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would approach this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="trail" match="*[not(self::A)]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::A[1])" />

<xsl:template match="/XMLCODE">
    <result>
        <xsl:for-each select="ex/A[position() mod 2 = 1]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('trail', generate-id())"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, this will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
   <k>want</k>
   <b>want</b>
   <j>want</j>
</result>
```

This is actually an XSLT 1.0 method. In XSLT 2.0 you could ostensibly do something with:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="ex/*" group-starting-with="A">
```

but I don't see an elegant method to distinguish between the "on" and "off" groups, since the first group could start with an `A` or not.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this XPath 1.0 expression**:

```
/*/ex/*[not(self::A or  self::B or self::C)
          and
            (
                preceding-sibling::A[1] | preceding-sibling::B[1] | preceding-sibling::C[1]
              )[last()][self::A]
          and
           (
              following-sibling::A[1] | following-sibling::B[1] | following-sibling::C[1]
            )[1][self::A]
            
   ]
```

---

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select=
     "/*/ex/*[
            not(self::A or  self::B or self::C)
          and
            (
                preceding-sibling::A[1] | preceding-sibling::B[1] | preceding-sibling::C[1]
              )[last()][self::A]
          and
           (
              following-sibling::A[1] | following-sibling::B[1] | following-sibling::C[1]
            )[1][self::A]

   ]"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<XMLCODE>
    <ex>
        <z>bla</z>
        <z>bla</z>
        <A/>
        <k>want</k>
        <b>want</b>
        <A/>
        <b>bla</b>
        <h>bla</h>
        <C/>
        <z>bla</z>
        <D/>
        <e>bla</e>
        <A/>
        <j>want</j>
        <A/>
        <i>bla</i>
        <C/>
        <y>bla</y>
        <C/>
        <y>bla</y>

    </ex>
</XMLCODE>
```

**The Xpath expression is evaluated and the results of this are copied to the output --the correct, wanted result is produced**:

```
<k>want</k>
<b>want</b>
<j>want</j>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do

```
let $A := //A
return for-each-pair(
         $A[position() mod 2 = 1], 
         $A[position() mod 2 = 0], 
         function($A1, $A2) {
           $A1/following-sibling::* intersect $A2/preceding-sibling::*
         }
       )
```

XPath 3.1 with higher-order function support but Saxon 10 and later in all editions, SaxonJS 2 and Saxon 9.8/9.9 PE/EE do that.

Answer (score 0):

Using [xslt-1.0](/questions/tagged/xslt-1.0) and [exslt](/questions/tagged/exslt) to extract element nodes between pairs of `A` elements:

```sh
xmlstarlet select -t \
  -m '*/*/A[following-sibling::A][count(preceding-sibling::A) mod 2 = 0]' \
    -c 'set:leading(following-sibling::*,following-sibling::A[1])' \
file.xml
```

- `-m` iterates over `A` element pairs, changing the context to the first `A`
- `-c` copies following sibling elements up to, and excluding, the second `A`

`set:leading` [documentation](https://exslt.github.io/set/functions/leading/index.html) on `github.io`,
[implementation](https://github.com/exslt/exslt.github.io/blob/master/set/functions/leading/set.leading.function.xsl) on `github.com`.

Output:

```xml
<k>want</k><b>want</b><j>want</j>
```

To have [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) `select` list the generated XSLT add a `-C`
option before `-t`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="exslt set">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="*/*/A[following-sibling::A][count(preceding-sibling::A) mod 2 = 0]">
      <xsl:copy-of select="set:leading(following-sibling::*,following-sibling::A[1])"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I would have thought that `<xsl:copy-of select="ex/*[not(self::A)][count(preceding-sibling::A) mod 2 = 1]" />` should be quite sufficient. However, it's horribly inefficient.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: with the current input file I think you're right, but it could return a false match if an unpaired `A` element exists.

Comment: I [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73916565/how-select-nodes-combining-preceding-sibling-and-following-sibling/73928806?noredirect=1#comment130514848_73916565) if the `A` elements come in pairs, and OP [confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73916565/how-select-nodes-combining-preceding-sibling-and-following-sibling/73928806?noredirect=1#comment130515378_73916565). Anyway, the point is about efficiency.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: I noticed that comment but decided it didn't rule out an odd number of target elements.

Comment: Well, then your definition of *pair* is different from mine. Anyway, the point is about efficiency.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Not definition but interpretation of OP's comment. Anyway, opting for [tag:exslt] I'm not so concerned about efficiency. I'm closing this comment thread.